# Failed to authenticate via ssh.Centos

Tags: centos, ssh

yesterday I was trying to authenticate via ssh "ssh demo" and return me the following error.

> ssh: connect to host ip port 7221: Connection refused

If you need more information I will provide it to you.
Kind Regards

ssh -vvv demo

```
    255 ↵  ‹ruby-2.2.0›
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/Administrator/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/Administrator/.ssh/config line 24: Applying options for demo
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 95.87.193.156 [95.87.193.156] port 7221.
debug1: connect to address 95.87.193.156 port 7221: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 95.87.193.156 port 7221: Connection refused
```

Comment: what is "demo" , is an entry in /etc/hosts/ maybe, or maybe an `~/.ssh/config` entry? are you sure SSH is served on 7221 port?

Comment: Yes demo is vm Ubuntu image on the Centos machine.Here is iptables --list on the cent machine.ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:7221.This is the port

Comment: please execute this on the VM `cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config | grep Port`

Comment: cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config | grep Port
#   Port 22

Comment: @D.Kamenov can you please edit your question and include the detail you've included here as comments.